# Timer isn't cancelled by timer.cancel()

Tags: android, timer

My Timer doesn't stop running if I cancel it!
The Timer only stops if I shut down the whole app!

I don't know why the Timer is not cancelled. If I print out every try on cancelling the Timer I get hundrets of lines but the Timer does not stop!

My Class:

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, MediaplayerEvent {

    //region Activity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Initialize_Layout();
        Initialize_Objects();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        MusicService.setMediaPlayerEvent(this);

        txvSongtitle.setText(serviceInterface.MP_getActualSong().getTitle());

        Start_Timer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        timer.cancel();

        MusicService.clearMediaPlayerEvent();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();

        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    //endregion

    //region Methods

    private void Start_Timer() {
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (serviceInterface.MP_isPlaying()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            seekBar.setMax(serviceInterface.MP_getDuration());
                            seekBar.setProgress(serviceInterface.MP_getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, 0, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            serviceInterface.MP_seekTo(progress);

            Start_Timer();
        }
    }

    //endregion
}
```

I hope you can help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Thread` instead of a Timer. Your `Start_Timer()`code would change to something like the following:

```
private Thread mTimerThread;

...

private void Start_Timer() {
    mTimerThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    if (serviceInterface.MP_isPlaying()) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                seekBar.setMax(serviceInterface.MP_getDuration());                       
                                seekBar.setProgress(serviceInterface.MP_getCurrentPosition());
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        interrupt();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    mTimerThread.start();
}
```

Threads are more efficient and lightweight and perfect for your needs. Plus, by setting the Thread to a global variable, you can make sure to call `mTimerThread.interrupt();` during Android lifecycle events, such as `onPause()`.

I hope this fixes your issue. Remember, the Java `Thread` is your friend!

Comment: ok thanks but why does it not work with the timer?

and know I know why I should use Threads :)

Comment: It was as the other answer said - you were creating a new timer every time you updated the progress bar, which was causing your problems. Glad it's fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating and starting a new timer the user moves the seekbar  (in `onProgressChanged()`). That also means you lose the reference to the old one. When isPlaying turns false, all the timers will try to cancel `timer` -- which only references the most recent one.